# How to explain binding energy of electron in Geant4 particle transport code?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, binding-energy

The question is related to binding energy of electrons in oxygen atom.
First I will put the question and later explain how did I came across it.

========= The question ===============

In the Geant4.10 code oxygen atom has 8 electrons, distributed on 4(!) shells, 
having binding energy $E_b$ as follows:

- first shell : 2 electrons:  $E_b = 543.1\,\mathrm{eV}$
- second shell: 2 electrons: $E_b = 41.6\,\mathrm{eV}$
- third shell: 2 electrons: $E_b = 28.48\,\mathrm{eV}$
- fourth shell: 2 electrons : $E_b = 13.62\,\mathrm{eV}$

See for reference the source code:
https://github.com/mortenpi/geant4/blob/master/source/materials/src/G4AtomicShells.cc
You can find there binding energies for other elements also.

**Do you have an idea from where these energies comes from ?**

Is my understanding correct that first shell corresponds orbital $1s^2$, second one $2s^2$, third and fourth belong to orbital $2p^4$.
If yes, why there is such a big difference in the binding energy between 3rd and 4th shell ($28.48$ vs $13.62\,\mathrm{eV}$).

In my naive understanding I would say that oxygen atom would have electrons on 3 energy levels (neglecting subtle quantum effects), corresponding to $1s^2$, $2s^2$ and $2p^4$ orbitals.
**Is it correct ?**

If you have no clue, I will ask Geant4 group, but there I would need to wait long for the answer.

========= The story ===============

I was simulating $4\,\mathrm{MeV}$ photons hitting a liquid water target with Geant4.10 Monte Carlo code.
In this scenario water was treated as a mixture of oxygen and hydrogen atoms with correct proportion, not as a molecule.
Following physical processes were simulated for photons:

- Rayleigh scattering
- Photoelectric effect
- Compton scattering
- gamma conversion (pair creation)

for electrons:

- Coulomb multiple scattering
- ionisation
- bremsstrahlung

In one of the events, primary photon of energy $4\,\mathrm{MeV}$, after passing of $21\,\mathrm{mm}$ of water undergone Compton scattering,
reducing its energy to $3166438.4\,\mathrm{eV}$, emitting an electron with energy $833520 \,\mathrm{eV}$ and spending $41.6\,\mathrm{eV}$ on binding energy.

Energy balance was:

- input

  - $4000000\,\mathrm{eV}$ (photon)
- output:

  - $3166438.4\,\mathrm{eV}$ (photon,  $79.161$% of input energy)
  - $833520\,\mathrm{eV}$ (electron,  $20.838$% of input energy)
  - $41.6\,\mathrm{eV}$ (binding energy, $0.001$% of input energy)

Primary photon changed also its direction and after passing another $152\,\mathrm{mm}$ undergone second Compton scattering,
reducing its energy to $1671825\,\mathrm{eV}$, emitting an electron with energy $1494584.9\,\mathrm{eV}$ and spending $28.5\,\mathrm{eV}$ on binding energy.

Energy balance:

- input

  - $3166438.4\,\mathrm{eV}$ (photon)
- output:

  - $1671825\,\mathrm{eV}$ (photon,  $52.7983$% of input energy)
  - $1494584.9\,\mathrm{eV}$ (electron,  $47.2008$% of input energy)
  - $28.5\,\mathrm{eV}$ (binding energy, $0.0009$% of input energy)

I know that this binding energy is negligible and comparable to gain of kinetic energy by oxygen atom itself ($0.003$ %),
nevertheless it gives an detail picture of what is really going in a Compton scattering.